# Why am I getting "NoSuchElementException" When I can print everything from textfile?

Tags: java, io, nosuchelementexception

I'm able to read everything from the text file and print the data yet I get a "No Such Element" Exception. All the solutions i've found say to use "HasNext" in while loop and yet it doesn't seem to work for me

public void fileReader() throws IOException {

```
    String id;
    String brand;
    int yearOfManufacture;
    int numSeats;
    double rentalPerDay;
    double insurancePerDay;
    double serviceFee;
    double discount;
    String model;
    String type;
    String color;
    ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleArray = new ArrayList<>();
    File file = new File("C:/Users/jockg/Downloads/Fleet (1).csv");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    scan.useDelimiter("n/n");

    while (scan.hasNext() || scan.hasNextDouble() || scan.hasNextInt()) {

        id = scan.next();
         System.out.println(id);
        brand = scan.next();
         System.out.println(brand);
        model = scan.next();
         System.out.println(model);
        type = scan.next();
         System.out.println(type);
        yearOfManufacture = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
         System.out.println(yearOfManufacture);
        numSeats = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
         System.out.println(numSeats);
        color = scan.next();
         System.out.println(color);
        rentalPerDay = Double.parseDouble(scan.next());
         System.out.println(rentalPerDay);
        insurancePerDay = Double.parseDouble(scan.next());
         System.out.println(insurancePerDay);
        serviceFee = Double.parseDouble(scan.next());
         System.out.println(serviceFee);
        if (scan.next().equals("N/A")) {
            discount = 0;
        } else {
            discount = Double.parseDouble(scan.next());
        }

         System.out.println(discount);

        Car newCar = new Car(id, brand, yearOfManufacture, numSeats, rentalPerDay, insurancePerDay, serviceFee,
                discount, model, type, color);
        vehicleArray.add(newCar);
    }
}
```

C001,Toyota,Yaris,Sedan,2012,4,Blue,50,15,10,10
C002,Toyota,Corolla,Hatch,2020,4,White,45,20,10,10
C003,Toyota,Kluger,SUV,2019,7,Grey,70,20,20,10
C004,Audi,A3,Sedan,2015,5,Red,65,10,20,10
C005,Holden,Cruze,Hatch,2020,4,Green,70,10,10,10
C006,BMW,X5,SUV,2018,7,White,100,25,20,10
C007,BMW,320i,Sedan,2021,5,Grey,75,10,15,N/A
C008,Ford,Focus,Sedan,2014,5,Red,45,10,10,N/A
C009,Ford,Puma,SUV,2015,5,Black,70,20,15,20

This is the Exception I get:

Comment: You're calling `scan.next()` ten times after checking once that `scan.hasNext()` so if any row does not have the required number of fields, you'll get an error.

Maybe use a CSV parsing library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- your CSV has actually two delimiters: comma and new line. Try: `scan.useDelimiter(",|\\R");`
- discount is read twice for numeric values, try:

```
    String discountStr = scan.next();
    discount = discountStr.equals("N/A") ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(discountStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (scan.next().equals("N/A")
```

might be your problem here. from what it looks like, this is not doing what you intend on doing.

When you call `scan.next()` it will read regardless of whether it is equal to "N/A"

you put an else statement after this and say `discount = Double.parseDouble(scan.next()` and I presume you are talking about the same `scan.next()` that you called in the initial if statement, but that line has already passed. You need to store this `scan.next()` in a variable and then check if it is "N/A".

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error after removing the if statement. Not too sure where to go with this one!